# How to exclude some columns from a pandas dataframe with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with shape(1000, 200).

Having 1000 rows and 200 columns, how do i find the most frequent value in each row and add the value to a new column.

I want to exclude first 5 columns from the final result.

The code:

```
      df['Mode'] = df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

does not work as required and includes all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({"Bye":[1,42,35,5],"c":[1,2,3,3],"d":[1,2,6,3],"f":[1,2,3,3],"e":[1,4,3,3]})
# output
    Bye c   d   f   e
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   42  2   2   2   4
2   35  3   6   3   3
3   5   3   3   3   3



df.iloc[:,2:].mode(axis=1)
#output
0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   3
```

First `locate` the elements on which you want to extract/calculate the mode.

`df.iloc[:,2:]` means we are going to take all the `rows` from the `df` and only the columns starting from `2+`. Then we apply the mode and select `axis=1` to calculate over the rows.

**Axis in pandas**

[image]

***Multiple Modes***

```
df77  = pd.DataFrame({"Bye":[1,42,35,5],"c":[1,42,3,3],"d":[2,7,6,3],"f":[2,7,3,3],"e":[3,4,3,3]})
df77

    Bye c   d   f   e
0   1   1   2   2   3
1   42  42  7   7   4
2   35  3   6   3   3
3   5   3   3   3   3

all_modes = df77.mode(axis=1)
all_modes.columns = ["mode1","mode2"] #renaming the modes because some rows had multiple ones

    mode1   mode2
0   1.0      2.0
1   7.0     42.0
2   3.0      NaN # indicates only 1 mode found
3   3.0      NaN


pd.concat([df77,all_modes],axis=1)

    Bye c   d   f   e   mode1   mode2
0   1   1   2   2   3    1.0    2.0
1   42  42  7   7   4    7.0    42.0
2   35  3   6   3   3    3.0    NaN
3   5   3   3   3   3    3.0    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @ombk for the answer. Still when i start it from 4+ columns and run the code with my data, i am not getting a single result but 5 columns starting from 0 until 4. Remember there are also NAN values in the rows.

Comment: this is not possible, you are probably writing it wrong.

Comment: @codingXP yes, as i said in my previous comment, you are not writing the code correctly. I applied the answer of the guy you accepted his answer, which is obviously same as mind but with more complication, and it gets the same result

Comment: This is what i am writing    print(df.iloc[:,5:].mode(axis=1)) to start from column no. 6. In the first column of the results, i believe i have the result but why its also showing other columns ?

Comment: Total 5 columns in the result when i print it. I think the rest of the columns are showing only NAN values. may be if i put dropna = True in the .mode() then it might remove the rest of the columns or may be numeric_only to true.

Comment: @codingXP that is because some of ur columns have `MULTIPLE` equal `MODES`

Comment: @codingXP if a column has 10 5s and another column has 10 7s , your output will show both modes

Comment: `A set of numbers can have more than one mode (this is known as bimodal if there are two modes) if there are multiple numbers that occur with equal frequency, and more times than the others in the set.` 
`If no number in a set of numbers occurs more than once, that set has no mode:`
`A set of numbers with two modes is bimodal, a set of numbers with three modes is trimodal, and any set of numbers with more than one mode is multimodal.`
Know your math, that is all i am saying

Comment: Yes that is possible. Because by default for pandas.Dataframe.Mode, dropna is true so i don't have to put dropna as True. So its a big problem and i have no idea how to solve it if there are multiple equal modes. Anyway thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Its an annotation dataset and mode is the gold label. Usually if you have a binary classification with two annotators, you might give preference to the annotator who is either expert or have importance due to any factor. In my case i have like more than 200 annotators and no idea in such a case which annotation value to chose to break the Tye between them.

Comment: @codingXP this is something different. I am just talking mathematically. the first guy is choosing `idxmax()` which means, the mode of the value that appears the last which is wrong. 5 5 5 6 2 2 2 has 2 modes, `5` and `2` . the first guy chooses `idxmax()` since the 2's comes after the 5's, it will take 2 as a mode and it is wrong. I am just arguing that.

Comment: So the only solution looks possible here is that i chose the answer having more values than NAN's in them.

Comment: @codingXP if you have 1 value and all the rest are NaNs it means you row has only 1 mode. In the other columns with multiple values it all goes to choose based on your knowledge in the domain...

Comment: Yes can u please update your answer to only add the first result column back to the original dataframe. Should i use df.apply ? as df['final'] =df.iloc[:,5:].mode(axis=1)) does not work and it gives an error.

Comment: yes because you are trying to allocate 1 column `final` with an unknown number of columns due to multiple modes. therefore, you can make a different dataframe and append them together.

Comment: @codingXP all is done... check the final answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking so much time and clarifying the issues. I really appreciate that..

Answer (score 1):

You need value_counts().idxmax() and make sure axis=1

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=1,high=6,size=(5,35)), columns=range(35))
print(df)
df['freq'] = df.apply((lambda x: (x[5:].mode())), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  ...  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34
0   1   4   4   1   1   5   1   2   3   2   1   1   2   2  ...   1   5   3   2   2   1   2   5   5   4   4   4   2   3
1   5   1   1   4   5   2   3   4   1   2   4   5   2   3  ...   2   5   1   5   3   4   1   5   5   3   2   4   1   3
2   5   2   1   3   1   2   2   5   5   4   5   5   1   2  ...   3   3   5   5   1   4   2   4   3   2   2   4   3   3
3   4   4   2   2   3   4   5   1   3   1   2   5   4   5  ...   3   4   5   3   3   5   2   1   5   1   1   4   4   3
4   5   3   1   5   2   4   2   5   3   4   1   3   4   1  ...   3   1   4   4   3   1   5   4   3   2   2   1   3   3

[5 rows x 35 columns]
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  ...  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  freq
0  1  4  4  1  1  5  1  2  3  2   1   1   2   2   1  ...   1   5   3   2   2   1   2   5   5   4   4   4   2   3     2
1  5  1  1  4  5  2  3  4  1  2   4   5   2   3   1  ...   2   5   1   5   3   4   1   5   5   3   2   4   1   3     5
2  5  2  1  3  1  2  2  5  5  4   5   5   1   2   2  ...   3   3   5   5   1   4   2   4   3   2   2   4   3   3     2
3  4  4  2  2  3  4  5  1  3  1   2   5   4   5   4  ...   3   4   5   3   3   5   2   1   5   1   1   4   4   3     5
4  5  3  1  5  2  4  2  5  3  4   1   3   4   1   1  ...   3   1   4   4   3   1   5   4   3   2   2   1   3   3     3

[5 rows x 36 columns]
```

Comment: @aaj kaal, basically ur method is wrong and let me tell u why... your method doesnt take into account if a row has multiple modes, it just takes the last most frequent element... it is sad it was chosen as answer and got 2 upvotes

Comment: @ombk thanks for bringing it up. Corrected it